# Use laravel Sanctum with a Vue SPA running localy on different Ports

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, vite

im learning to create a vue SPA with sanctum auth. i built a bit of my api and was testing with postman, adding the token for each protected post and get. That was working all fine. But now i have problems integrating my api into vite Vue project. using axios

I can get sanctum to store some cookies but still get 401 unauthorized when trying to access protected routes.

ive tried entering the following to support my vue localhost port but without luck:

`SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS = "localhost:5173"`

and i've set up the following defaults for axios in my vue project but they do not provide any difference:

`withCredentials = true; & withXSRFToken = true;`

tokens get stored but still get unatherized on any protected route
[image: tokens get stored but still get]

Any help would be nice

Comment: What is the value of `SESSION_DOMAIN`?

Comment: @tmath localhost, as all others return me a error in chrome network tag on the response header "this attempt to set a cookie was blocked .... because domain atribute was invalid in regard to current host url"

Comment: Ok, that's what it should be. I assume that your user is logged in when you try to access the protected routes, right? Because if not then 401 would be expected. Also note that by default after you register, the user is not logged in at that point.